# Use jq to recursively select key names of an object

Tags: json, recursion, key, yaml, jq

I have a JSON document that looks like:

```
simple: 42

normal:
  description: "NORMAL"

combo:
  one:
    description: "ONE"
  two:
    description: "TWO"
  arbitrary:
    foo: 42
```

I want to use a `jq` expression to generate the following:

```
["normal", "one", "two"]
```

The condition to select the key is that its corresponding value is an `object` type that has a key `description`. In this case, keys `simple` and `arbitrary` don't qualify.

I'm having a hard time to craft the filter. Looked into `with_entries` and `recurse/2` but can't solve it myself.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me whether the YAML that you gave is just a "view" of your JSON or whether you actually want to start with YAML. If your document really is YAML, then one approach would be to use a tool
(such as yaml2json or [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq)) to convert the yaml to JSON, and then run jq
as shown below; another would be to use jq as a text-processor,
but in that case you could just as well use awk.

```
yaml2json input.yaml |
  jq -c '[.. | objects | to_entries[] 
          | select(.value | has("description")?) | .key]'
```

#### Output

```
["normal","one","two"]
```

### Streaming parser

This type of problem is also well-suited to jq's streaming parser, which is especially handy when dealing with very large JSON texts.  Using `jq --stream`, a suitable jq filter would be:

```
[select(length==2) | .[0] | select(.[-1] == "description") | .[-2]]
```

The ordering of the results will depend on the ordering of the keys produced by the YAML-to-JSON conversion tool.

Comment: Perfect. You were right: I was trying to solve the problem with yq but couldn't. Your solution was correct and spot on, and even provided alternatives. Excellent! TY!